# is it possible to use variables from 2 instances together inside a method?

Tags: python, class

I'm sorry if I phrased this wrong, but I will try my best to explain what I want to do.

Is it possible to do this in Python -

```
class Character():
    strength, skill = 0, 0

    def foo(self, strength, skill):
        if c1.strength > c2.strength:
            #something here

c1 = Character()
c2 = Character()

c1.strength = 15
c2.strength = 13
```

I don't really know how to explain this, but what I am trying to do is use the variables from the two instances that I made, inside the method?

Would that code work, or is there anything else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just pass the other instance:

```
def foo(self, other_character):
    if self.strength > other_character.strength:
        #something here

c1 = Character()
c2 = Character()

c1.strength = 15
c2.strength = 13

c1.foo(c2)
```

Comment: You will need to pass the 2nd character as an argument to the first, like this.